# How do I run GDB one instruction a time?

Tags: gdb

I am on Linux, on x86-64 CPU. I want to run a certain assembly stub exactly one instrucion at a time.
"s" does not work. This stub is part of a shared object and has no line informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to run a certain assembly stub exactly one instrucion at a
> time. "s" does not work

Use `nexti` command several times until the assembly stub ends. See [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html).